# Как попросить скринридер прочитать контент, подгруженный через AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

Решил попробовать заморочиться с доступностью и споткнулся об то, что всякие современные SPA подгружают контент через AJAX и модифицируют страницу через JavaScript, а скринридеры об этом не очень в курсе. Из гуглинга я понял, что нужно что-то делать с HTML-атрибутом `aria-live`, но какого-то внятного результата добиться не смог. Код, с которым я сейчас играюсь:

```js
let clicks = 0;

const contentHtml = `
<ul>
  <li>Раз, два.</li>
  <li>Три, четыре.</li>
</ul>
<p>Пять, шесть.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="loadContent();">Нажми меня</button>
`;

function loadContent() {
  // Имитация ajax-запроса
  setTimeout(updateContent, 500);
}

function updateContent() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = `Кликов: ${clicks}!`;
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = `<em>Номер клика: ${clicks}!</em><br/>` + contentHtml;
}
```

```html
<h1 aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="all">
  <div id="title">Заголовок</div>
</h1>

<nav><a href="#">Ссылка</a></nav>

<main aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="all">
  <div id="content">
    <p>Исходный контент.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadContent();">Нажми меня</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Я хочу, чтобы после нажатия кнопки скринридер прочитал обновившиеся заголовок и контент и желательно не читал ссылку из навигации.

Что я в идеале хочу услышать:

> *Кликов: один. Номер клика: один. Раз, два. Три, четыре. Пять, шесть. Нажми меня (нажимаемая кнопка).*

Что я слышу в Chromium (дублирование и неправильный порядок, причём каждый раз порядок разный):

> *Раз, два. Номер клика: один. Раз, два. Три, четыре. Пять, шесть. Пять, шесть. Три, четыре. Нажми меня.*

Что я слышу в Firefox (куда потерялись заголовок, номер клика и кнопка?):

> *Раз, два. Три, четыре. Пять, шесть.*

Что мне предпринять, чтобы обновлённый контент читался нормально? Или это баги браузеров и я ничего не смогу предпринять?

Сейчас я слушаю в Kubuntu 22.04 со встроенным в него Orca, если это имеет значение.

UPD: если добавить `aria-atomic="true"`, то Firefox начинает повторять контент целых четыре раза, а Chromium так и продолжает беспорядочно читать.